# Custom UITableViewCell layout on scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, scroll, custom-cell

I have a UITableView with custom cells. Since I was unable to add constraints to my labels, I tried to do this programmatically. Now everything is working except when I start scrolling. Somehow the layoutsubviews method is ignored or reset.

**TableViewController.m**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    SubjectCell *cell = (SubjectCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];

    cell.subjectLabel.text = [tentamenArray objectAtIndex:currentRow][@"SUMMARY"];

    return cell;
}
```

**SubjectCell.m**

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGSize screen = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    [_subjectLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 15, screen.width - 70, 20)];
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use `- (void)prepareForReuse` method instead?

Answer (score 0):

Make `subjectLabel` publicly accessible and change the frame of it within the ViewController itself.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    SubjectCell *cell = (SubjectCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];

    cell.subjectLabel.text = [tentamenArray objectAtIndex:currentRow][@"SUMMARY"];

    CGSize screen = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    [cell.subjectLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 15, screen.width - 70, 20)];

    return cell;
}
```